# How to display single row in ng-repeat, in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am very new to AngularJs and trying to use it in my project. I made a WebApi function that returns a city's current temperature. From html, I want to get that single temperature and display it. I know ng-repeat is used to display many items but how to display a single item.

my current code is below. I expected to display "20" as temperature, but it displays "2" and "0" in two rows :) Please help. How can I display it as "20" in a single row?

```
<div ng-controller="WearherController">
    <table ng-repeat="weather in weathers" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>{{weather}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
....
....
....
<script>
var app = angular.module("ZenHaberApp", []);
app.controller("WeatherController", function ($scope, $http) {
    var city = 'Adana';
    $http.get('http://localhost:62747/api/getweatherbycityname/' + city).
      success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          $scope.weathers = data.condition_temp;

      }).
      error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
          alert("error");
      });
});
</script>
```

I think @Sajeetharan gave me the solution but now it displays a silly image. What is it? How can I fix this?
[image]

here is the rest of the code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("ZenHaberApp", []);
    app.controller("WeatherController", function ($scope, $http) {
        var city = 'Adana';
        $http.get('http://localhost:62747/api/getweatherbycityname/' + city).
          success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              $scope.weathers = data.condition_temp;

          }).
          error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
              alert("error");
          });
    });
</script>
```

SOLUTION:

thanks to @Sajeetharan, he found out the problem. It was {{weather}}

It should be {{weathers}}

Comment: that is the cell , can you post what is inside $scope.weathers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly assign the $scope variable **`weathers`**,

```
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>{{weathers}}</td>
        </tr>
 </table>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/WGDFkNISkeKGrfPzPQ3r?p=info)**

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan, thanks for your time. I think your answer is correct but it displays a silly image. What is it? I posted that image above in my question

Comment: that is the cell , can you post what is inside $scope.weathers?

Comment: I added $scope.weathers

Comment: @ayilmaz not that brother, just add a console.log and see what is being printed in console console.log($scope.weathers);

Comment: It prints "20" as I expected. But it doesnt go into the html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127008/discussion-between-ayilmaz-and-sajeetharan).

Comment: Thank you very much @Sajeetharan, you helped a lot